# Quick question about relational one-to many database

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, data-modeling

I'm doing a venue/events database and I've created my tables and would like some confirmation from someone if I did everything right :)

I have 2 tables:

- Venues
- Events

The primary key of `Venues` is VENUE_ID, which is set to auto_increment. I have the same column in `Events`, which will contain the number of the Venue ID.  This should connect them, right?

Also, the table engine is MyISAM.

Comment: can a venue have multiple events? can an event have multiple venue?

Comment: It will connect them logically, but not physically. If your goal is to have events be removed when you remove a venue, then you must use InnoDB and a foreign key.

Comment: @BookOfZeus This model would handle multiple events per venue.

Comment: A venue can have multiple events, while an event can have only one venue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not automatically link the tables to each others, and the referenced columns don't necessarily have to have the same name (in fact, there are situations where this is impossible: e.g. when a table has two columns that both reference the same column in another table).

Read up on foreign keys; they're standard SQL and do exactly what you want. Note, however, that the MyISAM storage engine cannot enforce foreign key constraints, so as long as any of the tables involved uses MyISAM, the foreign key declaration doesn't add much (it does, however, document the relationship, at least in your SQL scripts).

I suggest you use InnoDB (or, if that's feasible, switch to PostgreSQL - not only does it provide foreign key constraints, it also has full support for transactions, unlike MySQL, which will silently commit a pending transaction whenever you do something that's not supported in a transaction, with potentially devastating results). If you have to / want to use MySQL, I suggest you use InnoDB for everything, unless you know you need the extra performance you can get out of MyISAM *and* you can afford the caveats. Also keep in mind that migrating large tables from MyISAM to InnoDB later in production can be painful or even outright impossible.

Comment: Oracle, SQL Server, etc support implicit transactions -- it's a configuration setting.  And DDL statements are always implicit commit/rollback on error...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Oracle and SQL Server are both proprietary, and they're both expensive.

Comment: MySQL has "proprietary" functionality too: FIND_IN_SET, GROUP_CONCAT, the list goes on...  ANSI is a nice idea, but some aspects don't work as well as native functionality (besides the fact of piecemeal implementation by vendors).  The Express versions of Oracle & SQL Server are also free to use.  None of which has anything to do with your statement about implicit commits...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The sane behavior when something occurs in a transaction that shouldn't, or isn't supported, is to rollback and raise an error. MySQL instead silently commits and carries on outside the transaction. This is seldom desirable, and unlike other DBMS's, MySQL does not offer any way to override this behavior that I am aware of. Also, DDL statements do not implicitly rollback or commit in Postgres; just like SQL Server, Postgres offers transactional DDL: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis

Comment: You admit you don't know, but will still continue to tell me/everyone how MySQL works? ;)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You made me google... anyway, apparently there is no way to override MySQL's auto-commit-on-DDL behavior without altering the source, as it's hard-coded.

Comment: @OMGPonies let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2943/discussion-between-tdammers-and-omg-ponies)

Answer (score 2):

Your db structure is right.
You can use Innodb for adding foreign key contraints. Also don't forget to add index to the second table for faster joining two tables.

More info about FK http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Note to comments:
Innodb allows you to make concurrent select/(insert/update) but MyIsam allows you to do the same things if you don't delete from MyIsam table. Otherwise MyIsam will lock your whole table.

Comment: I thought about that but then I read that InnoDb is best at writing/updating rows which I won't be really doing - just selecting.

Comment: Read note about myisam/innodb

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes.  This is how you indicate a one-to-many relation between two tables.  You may also specifically encode the relationship into the database by setting up a Foreign Key constraint.  This will allow add'l logic such as cascading.

Comment: [MYISAM doesn't support FKs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I think it's a horrible convention. The column name in the referring table should indicate the *role* that column plays in the relation, not the name of the referred column - with any decent DMBS, the technical information is already present in the FK definitions, while the functional information should be apparent from the column names. `documents.owner_id -> users.id` is much more speaking than `documents.user_id -> users.user_id`; in fact, the latter is even misleading, as `user_id` indicates the person who owns the document, not necessarily the one who uses it.

Comment: @tdammers: Anyone new to the database won't know that relationship unless they check the foreign key constraints -- it fails Spolsky's Hallway Test.  Making the related columns the same or very similar names saves a lot of time & effort.